# System.InvalidOperationException: 'SQLBASEOLEDB.1' provider not registered on local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, sqlbase

I get the following error message in my browser when calling a method of an `ASP.NET` `Webservice`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'SQLBASEOLEDB.1' provider not registered on local machine
```

I tried the solution indicated in this [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/417397/OLEDB-Provider-is-Not-Registered-on-the-Local-Mach):

Which basically consists of changing the solution platform from "Any `CPU` to "x86"" but I still get the same error. How can I fix that?

Comment: That's a third party provider, have you installed it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQLBase 32bit or 64bit.

Open the Registry Editor (regedit.exe), and navigate to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes (or HKCR).
Scroll down and look for SQLBASEOLEDB.
You'll see several entries:
SQLBASEOLEDB - Unversioned, points to most recently installed version (not necessarily highest version)
SQLBASEOLEDB.1 - Same as above
SQLBASEOLEDB.12 - Specific version for SQLBase 12 (same major version)
SQLBASEOLEDB.120 - Specific version for SQLBase 12.0 (same major and minor version)

All entries except for SQLBASEOLEDB.120 are only *links* to said entry. Testing SQLBASEOLEDB.120 ***directly*** avoids the indirection, which might be the issue.

OR, There might be a bug in the registration.

- You can test the driver by creating a UDL file (empty file with .udl extension), then double-clicking it. Go to the 'Providers' tab, then select SQLBase and click 'Next'. Keep in mind, on 64-bit machines, this will use the 64-bit version of the OLEDB driver.
- If you are using SQLBase 32bit , re-register the dll using 
  %windir%\syswow64\regsvr32.exe path/to/sqlbaseoledb.dll
- If you are using SQLBase 64bit, re-register the dll using 
  %windir%\System32\regsvr32.exe path/to/sqlbaseoledb.dll

When the OLEDB driver is actually successfully installed by regsvr32 as prompted after the manual installation process, the error message : "SQLBaseOLEDB-Provider is not registered on this local machine".
is very misleading ..
Solution:
ALL your exes should be compiled with the x86 switch instead
of the "any cpu" switch to get them run on 64 bit machines. ALL of them - any in your stack that has the "any cpu" option set will caused problems. After setting this switch to x86, everything should work fine, after you re-register the dll manually.